# Rejected error on push repository in Gitlab

Tags: git

I want to push some test file to the `myfirstgittrial` project on GitLab.

When i run this `git push origin master` command on ubuntu terminal I got this error

```
To git@gitlab.com:RamS20_2/myfirstgittrial.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:RamS20_2/myfirstgittrial.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

And my Origin value is

```
origin  git@gitlab.com:RamS20_2/myfirstgittrial.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.com:RamS20_2/myfirstgittrial.git (push)
```

Comment: As the message says, your branch is behind, so do a `git pull` to get he latest from the server, resolve any conflicts, and then you'll be able to `push`.

Comment: I tried ```git pull origin master``` and it result 
```From gitlab.com:RamS20_2/myfirstgittrial
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```
and i also try to push but i got same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Error clearly says your branch is behind,
So first do

1.`git pull`

2. `git add .`
3. `git commit -m "message"`
4. `git push origin master`  or  `git push`

Hope this helps